# How do I extract data from a node in a linked list in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, nodes

How do you access data in a linked list?  Mainly, I have two specific questions.  I'm a beginner in python and just learning linked lists so bear with me if this seems like a stupid question.

1. I have a linked list of nodes where each node is an instance of a class.
   How do I retrieve the node in the linked list with a certain instance attribute = x?
2. I have a linked list of nodes where each node is a dictionary.
   How do I search for a node in the linked list with a certain key in Python?

Currently, I am unable to access the information in the node except for printing it using the **str** method.

Comment: Can you share the code snippet? I will be able to explain better from the code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data in a linked list is accessed by traversing the list. You need to start at the head, check if the data it contains is what you're looking for, and traverse to the next node if it isn't.

So, making some assumptions about your implementation of linked lists:

1. You will need to start at the head node and traverse your list until you find the desired data attribute value.

You can do this with a function that returns None if the desired data attribute value isn't in the linked list. I'll assume your linked list nodes have a method, next_node, which returns None if it's the tail instance.

```
def traverse_to_desired_node(head : LinkedListNode, desired : Any):
    node = head
    while node.data != desired:
        node = node.next_node()
        if node is None:
            return None
    return node
```

2. If each node in a linked list is a dictionary, that means your linked list is really a nested dict with each nested dict contained within a key, 'next' or something, and the tail has None as the value of 'next'.

A similar approach will work:

```
def traverse_to_desired_node(head : dict, desired : str):
    node = head
    while desired not in node:
        node = node['next']
        if node is None:
            return None
    return node
```

Now, with either approach, you can set a variable to the node:

```
node = traverse_to_node(head, 'desired')
```

Then, if it's a class instance, you can access the data attribute of that node:

```
print(node.data)
```

Or, if it's a dict, access the desired key:

```
print(node['desired'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually you just need to define a recursive function. Assuming your linked list is defined as follows:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.next = None
```

Now traversing the list and finding a node with a specific value is fairly easy:

```
def find(node: Node, search_val):
    if not node:
        return None
    else:
        if node.val == search_val:
            return node
        else:
            return find(node.next, search_val)
```

Similarly you can modify this function to check whether `node.val` is a dictionary and whether it has a certain key.

Question 2 is phrased in a strange way. Node cannot be a dictionary. It has to be some form of Node class. It can contain a dictionary, but it can't be one.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I actually was able to figure out a piece of code I was stuck on for hours from your comment.  I completely forgot that I was able to access node.data (similar to node.val) in your code snippet.